# Class Definition for Cached JSON

Tags: python, json, itunes

I am trying to define a class that returns a dictionary with song title,the track number and genre type( this is from an itunes API request for songs by a particular artist). Currently when I run my file in terminal nothing is being returned( I am not receiving a syntax error or traceback). I am expecting to see a dictionary with the track name, track number and alternative genre. Any help would be great!

```
class Song():
def __init__(self, song_dict={}):
    self.trackName = song_dict["trackName"]
    self.trackNumber = song_dict["trackNumber"]
    self.genre = song_dict["primaryGenreName"]["alternative"]
def __str__(self):

return "{} by {}".format(self.trackName,self.trackNumber,self.genre)
```

Cached JSON:

```
{"http://itunes.apple.com/searchcountry-US_entity-song_format-json_term-bon+iver": {"resultCount": 50, "results": [{"collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit", "releaseDate": "2011-06-21T07:00:00Z", "currency": "USD", "artistId": 273428126, "previewUrl": "http://audio.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview71/v4/29/b7/6d/29b76dbc-c7c2-a528-98c0-88250c90d61f/mzaf_8791054078902679680.plus.aac.p.m4a", "trackPrice": 1.29, "isStreamable": true, "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/holocene/id438685974?i=438685989&uo=4", "collectionName": "Bon Iver", "collectionId": 438685974, "trackId": 438685989, "collectionViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/holocene/id438685974?i=438685989&uo=4", "trackCount": 10, "trackNumber": 3, "discNumber": 1, "collectionPrice": 9.99, "trackCensoredName": "Holocene", "trackName": "Holocene", "trackTimeMillis": 336613, "primaryGenreName": "Alternative", "artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/bon-iver/id273428126?uo=4", "kind": "song", "country": "USA", "wrapperType": "track", "artworkUrl100": "http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/f6/41/9b/f6419bd5-7fa7-6046-04d0-fcae6ecf9d96/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionCensoredName": "Bon Iver", "artistName": "Bon Iver", "artworkUrl60": "http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/f6/41/9b/f6419bd5-7fa7-6046-04d0-fcae6ecf9d96/source/60x60bb.jpg", "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit", "artworkUrl30": "http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/f6/41/9b/f6419bd5-7fa7-6046-04d0-fcae6ecf9d96/source/30x30bb.jpg", "discCount": 1}, {"contentAdvisoryRating": "Explicit", "collectionExplicitness": "explicit", "releaseDate": "2010-11-22T08:00:00Z", "currency": "USD", "artistId": 2715720, "previewUrl": "http://a1044.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/ac/5a/7b/mzm.wurlfubj.aac.p.m4a", "trackPrice": 1.29, "isStreamable": true, "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/monster-feat-jay-z-rick-ross-nicki-minaj-bon-iver/id403822142?i=403822318&uo=4", "collectionName": "My Beautiful Dark Twisted Fantasy", "collectionId": 403822142, "trackId": 403822318, "collectionViewUrl":
```

Comment: You haven't said what problem you are encountering. There are at least four things wrong with this code: indentation, returning things from an init method, unnecessary equals signs between the song_dict and its keys, and the mutable default argument.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. First, you have some equal signs (meaning, assignments) that you don't need/want. This:

   ```
   self.trackName =song_dict["trackName"]
   self.trackNumber=song_dict=["trackNumber"]
   self.primaryGenreName =song_dict=["primaryGenreName"]
   ```

   Should become this:

   ```
   self.trackName = song_dict["trackName"]
   self.trackNumber = song_dict["trackNumber"]
   self.primaryGenreName = song_dict["primaryGenreName"]
   ```
2. Next, you don't return things from a class constructor (`__init__`) in Python. So delete the return statement.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I removed the equal signs and the return statement. Anymore advice? Thanks!